# NetSuite - how to create reference link

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

When the billing schedule runs it auto generates invoices from sales order. When this happens - how can I create a link on the sales order that will allow me to load the corresponding invoice in code?

I need this so I can grab couple of field values from the invoice but I can't access the invoice directly from another entity which seems only related to sales order.

EDIT 1:

```
var fil = [];
fil[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('createdfrom', null, 'is', nlapiGetRecordId())
var col = [];
col[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
var invoices = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', null, fil, col);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'field val', invoices);
```

Throws invalid operator or not in proper syntax: createdfrom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though adding a link on the Sales Order is a viable solution, it's not your only option. Alternatively, you could do a search for invoices where the `createdfrom` field is the internal ID of your Sales Order. Something like in SuiteScript 1.0:

```
var invoices = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', null,
    [['createdfrom', 'is', nlapiGetRecordId()]],
    [/* create search columns for the fields you need off the invoice */]
) || [];
```

or in 2.0:

```
var invoices = search.create({
  "type": search.Type.INVOICE,
  "filters": [['createdfrom', 'is', context.currentRecord.id]],
  "columns": [/* create search columns for the fields you need off the invoice */]
}).run().each(processResult);
```

This will get you a list of all the Invoices created from your Sales Order (which is likely only 1).

If you believe you need a link to the Invoice on the Sales Order, you could add the custom body field, then create a User Event on the Invoice record that populates this new field with its `createdfrom` value on the Before Submit event. But then what happens if your Sales Order gets paid via multiple Invoices?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are you saying the createdfrom is a build in field? The createfrom field i see on the invoice form doesn't hold the internid rather a string like: "Sales Order #SO -6"

Comment: @MG2016 `createdfrom` is the standard internal id for `Sales Order #SO`

Comment: This returns an invalid operator or not in proper syntax: createdfrom.